# When setting display to block of TD in CSS to make cell clickable, they get horribly resized / HTML - CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I'm trying to make a cell table with only HTML + CSS, and have done an alright job I'm happy with except for the clickability. Only the link was clickable, so when I went into the CSS to change the display to block and the width to 100%, my proportions went wacko and it didn't work like it should have. How would I go about fixing this?

```css
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
td:hover {
background: #c2ceb5;
}
/*]]>*/
    
td a {
    display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}
    
</style>

#HTML -#
```

```html
<table align="" style="border: 0px solid #ffffff; background-color: #5e913f;" class="mceEditable" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" height="277" width="1060">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Motorcycles" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pb951b66bb569142b/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Motorcycles</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Compacts" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p6b71aa99c4644cd3/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Compacts</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Coupes" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p6910e9886b0d0a84/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Coupes</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;"><a class="" title="Sedans" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p04487d08f78ab32f/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Sedans</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Sports" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p2309313bdad3caca/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Sports</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Sports Classics" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pfdf6e03bcaf0041a/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Sports Classics</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Super" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p792868a4260dfc77/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Super</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Muscle" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pb6ced3f8242bb598/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Muscle</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Off-Road" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pc08e3cf76c44bace/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Off-Road</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="SUVs" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p27252c4e66b73e8c/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">SUVs</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Vans" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p50a19d54db1172f4/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Vans</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Industrial" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pda5c3f1364fe4017/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Industrial</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Commercials" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p7447d89331c6609b/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Commercial</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Utility" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p95dac2582026e810/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Utility</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Emergency" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p88e7120effd6ec2d/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Emergency</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Service" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pe1b688a7fc1a8110/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Service</span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Comment: Seems to be working, what is wrong?

Comment: This is not tabular data, so you shouldn't use tabular elements. You can use CSS tables instead.

Comment: What browser have you tested on? It looks OK to me on the latest Windows Chrome. Could you attach a screenshot of the bad display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-element with `absolute` positioning so that it will span to the whole cell's area (just remember to set `td {position: relative}`). That way the link will be taking the whole space, but the sole content of it (i.e. text etc.) won't get messed up:

(***I've set the semi-transparent red background on the pseudo-element so it's better visible what's going on.*** In your final code just leave the `background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);` out)

```css
td a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}
td a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
  <table align="" style="border: 0px solid #ffffff; background-color: #5e913f;" class="mceEditable" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" height="277" width="1060">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Motorcycles" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pb951b66bb569142b/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Motorcycles</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Compacts" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p6b71aa99c4644cd3/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Compacts</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Coupes" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p6910e9886b0d0a84/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Coupes</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;"><a class="" title="Sedans" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p04487d08f78ab32f/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Sedans</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Sports" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p2309313bdad3caca/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Sports</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Sports Classics" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pfdf6e03bcaf0041a/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Sports Classics</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Super" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p792868a4260dfc77/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Super</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Muscle" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pb6ced3f8242bb598/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Muscle</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Off-Road" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pc08e3cf76c44bace/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Off-Road</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="SUVs" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p27252c4e66b73e8c/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">SUVs</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Vans" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p50a19d54db1172f4/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Vans</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Industrial" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pda5c3f1364fe4017/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Industrial</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Commercials" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p7447d89331c6609b/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Commercial</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; height: 50px;"><a class="" title="Utility" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p95dac2582026e810/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Utility</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Emergency" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/p88e7120effd6ec2d/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Emergency</span></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff;"><a class="" title="Service" href="/app/sdfb0ab666d755ac0/pe1b688a7fc1a8110/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Service</span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! That's something I never would have thought of, but I feel as though I should have. Thank you! One more thing though, with everything set, the text seems to float to the top a little. Any way I can fix that?

Comment: Yeah, those pseudo-elements. Saved me more time that I would suppose when I first started using them ;)

Comment: Sure, glad to be of help. Consider accepting / upvoting the answer after you'll be positive it did solved your issue :) As for the text being to close to the top, I don't see it after running my snippet. Maybe you left the `height: 100%` on your `td a`? It _would_ mess this up in the way you're describing it.

Comment: Haha my bad, that's what I did. I'll be happy to upvote!